# Are augmented and extended matrices the same?

Tags: matrices

Before turning in a lecture that says this is fact, I want to check with all of you.

Are augmented and extended matrices the same thing with different titles?

If they are not, can someone explain the difference to me. Thanks!

Comment: Neither "Augmented matrix" or "Extended matrix" have any standard definition. I think you might be in the context of linear algebra and the Gauss algorithm (or maybe simplex algorithm?). There it is very well possible that these terms are used interchangable, but that depends on the author/teacher/book/whatever. It is simply not a precisely defined term.

Comment: This is indeed a lecture for linear algebra. I had always seen it as augmented but my professor and text both use extended.